# Should I mention studying during high school in academic CV?

Tags: mathematics, cv

I am a postdoc, applying for tenure track jobs in mathematics.
I did my bachelor degree as a kid (was 14 when started).
I wonder if I should/could mention this in my academic CV?

Comment: It is your CV, you can do what you like with it.

Comment: Of course I can do what I want, my question is it is advisible to do that.

Comment: That all depends on who is reading it. The answer is simple: if you are proud of it, mention it. If not, don't. There are no rules for a CV: it is your personal CV so do what you like.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you mean that you did high school and college concurrently?

Comment: I wouldn't do this in the US, for the simple reason that age discrimination is illegal. Formally, I'm not _allowed_ to care how old you are, or how old you were when you got whatever degree; I'm only allowed to care about what you've _done_.

Comment: You should clarify the title, since I think everyone "studied" in high school (at least a little bit)

Answer (score 2):

In my academic CV, I have included all my university education, which naturally includes my undergraduate degree.

I don't think it makes any difference that you started when you were 14. You came out with the same piece of paper as everyone else in the end up.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the question is about whether to just mention the BSc, or whether to also mention that it was obtained in parallel to attending highschool.

Answer (score 1):

It possibly depends on *where* you are sending the CV. For a research position, it clearly indicates intelligence and thus probably would help or at least not hurt (as long as you don't overplay it). For more of a teaching job (e.g. at a 4-year college) I could see how it might *potentially* hurt: if you didn't have the typical high school math background you might have difficulty teaching students who have just come from that (with all of the gaps and weaknesses such a background so often entails).

Perhaps you can prepare two different versions of your CV, one that contains the parenthetical (started at age 14) and one that doesn't. For each job you apply to, make a judgment call about which one to send, taking into account both the job description and the nature of the school.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very similar situation: Started my BSc with 13, got it with 16 and was looking for a faculty level position in Math or CS [plenty of other things happened in between].

My CV does mention this. It never came up during an interview, or informal feedback, neither in a positive or negative way. I got a position.

Of course, this is just a single data point, but maybe it helps.

Comment: This is a good thing though. It is indeed an achievement in starting Bachelor study at the age of 13 (or 14). In my country, it is not allowed. It should definitely be mentioned. I don't know how much it is normal it is in other countries.